# Button loses css styling when clicked and loading

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, styling

I can't seem to figure this out. When I click my button and it's loading the target page, the button loses its text styling. The original button styling is being pulled from the wordpress theme I'm using. I've included a gif and the code for reference. Any ideas?

See in action: https://imgflip.com/gif/197tc9

```
    .darkbutton {
    color: #fff !important;
    border: 2px solid #fff !important;
    background-color: #0be2a1 !important;
    margin-top: 4px !important;
}

    .darkbutton:hover {
    color: #0be2a1 !important;
    border: 2px solid #fff !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: show us some of your code?

Comment: show us your html part

Comment: Stop using `!important;` If you need to add that to every single property, you need to write better markup. It should be used *as a last resort*, not in every single line of your CSS. Chances are the overuse of `!important;` is causing the display issues you are having.

Comment: If you don't post the code Imma go batshit

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use focus state of CSS

```
.darkbutton:focus {
 color: #fff !important;
}
```